# Water animation works in viewport but renders differently (cycles)

Tags: animation, 3d-view

I have made a simple water text animation using canvas and brush, when i run it in the viewport it looks amazing causing ripples as a sphere glides through the text, however when i set the render animation up and hit render it renders the animation with just the ball going through the text but no amazing ripple effect, i am using blender version 2.8.3

Thanks
Stuart

Comment: I can move the timeline position anywhere and render image and it is correct

Comment: https://youtu.be/VeGHNcOedAw

This is the tutorial that i am trying to replicate in Blender 2.8.3

Comment: I have just downloaded Blender version 2.79 and the tutorial works fine and renders fine, I am assuming that this is a bug in Blender 2.8.3 if anyone else can try this tutorial i would be very grateful, it is only a short one thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that in the tutorial i was trying to follow the guy dosent bake the Dynamic paint where as in newer versions of Blender you need to open up the cache section of Dynamic Paint and click on the bake dynamics button